# How do you edit a database migration?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, code-first

I renamed a few tables and some columns. When I run the `Add-Migration` command, the migration generates code that drops the old tables and columns and adds ones with the new names. This results in losing the data they contained.

Since I don't want to lose the data, I want to edit the migration, removing the drop and add commands, and replacing them with rename commands.

But after I edit a migration, how do I apply that change?

If I run the `Update-Database` command, that applies it to the database. But not to the snapshot that Entity Framework maintains of my schema (stored in `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot`).

I need a way to incorporate my edits into the model. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can edit the migration file.

Comment: Very good. Except that doesn't update the snapshot. Please see my question.

Comment: Why do you need to change snapshot?

Comment: Because otherwise, the next time I do `Add-Migration`, it doesn't recognize my edits and treats the schema as though my changes don't exist. It only recognizes the changes that are incorporated into the snapshot.

Comment: When you have generated the drop/create migration it should have created the snapshot with needed structure, you need to change the migration to renames so it fits the new snapshot.

Comment: @GuruStron: From what I'm seeing, that doesn't update the snapshot. And so the next `Add-Migration` will not recognize the changes I made. Not sure how I can explain that more clearly.

Comment: So basically you are saying that  `Add-Migration` which drops/creates tables does not update the snapshot? It is very strange.

Comment: @GuruStron: No, I am not saying that. `Add-Migration` works as expected. It creates the migration and applies it to the snapshot. My question is what if I then come in and edit the migration? The generated migration was applied to the snapshot. My edits are not.

Comment: You should change the migration only in a way that database will end up in the correct state. So your edits should lead to the same database structure as the generated code."Drop `TableA` + Create `TableAA`" and "rename `TableA` to `TableAA` are the same from snapshot point of view, so you can change your migration from drop/create to rename, but you should not add any other changes in this migration.

Comment: @GuruStron: Maybe. I screwed up. I should've made one small change at a time. Instead, I renamed a bunch of stuff in one step. So the edit will be complex, and ensuring it produces exactly the same result will be non-trivial.

Comment: You can wipe everything down and start from scratch, but yes, AFAIK this is only possible approach to manually editing migrations - they should produce output consistent 
 with the snapshot (unless you want to edit it manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is definitely the messy part of code first.

As far as the question asked, as [GuruStron suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080405/how-do-you-edit-a-database-migration/63090880#comment111549388_63080405), the only way I found to have a valid custom migration is to edit it such that the result is the same as what the original, generated migration produced. This keeps it up to date with the database snapshot. And running `Update-Database` will run your custom update code.

I think my biggest problem was that I had too many changes going on at once. After struggling with this for a while, I undid some of my changes and added them back bit-by-bit. Entity Framework will rename a table or column if it can figure out that the new name refers to the same column. If it finds many changes, it can't figure this out.

In the end, I had to customize the migration a little for a couple of columns that were being dropped (customized them to be renamed instead). But I was able to get Entity Framework to rename my tables and other columns.

The key: make small changes at a time and carefully review the migration before applying them to the database. If you need to customize the migration, do it such that the end result doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need to drop a column in one table and add it to a different table but since the column in the original table has data in it you do NOT want to lose. You change the entities to accomplish this and do the migrations ...but... the column is empty in the new table. So you could edit the C# migration file to:

1. Create a new column in destination table.
2. Copy the data from the source column to the destination column.
3. Delete the source table column.

This not contrived, it is a real need.

Answer (score -2):

**You don't.**

I suppose you are developing using a code first approach, since the question has this tag on it.

### If you are using code first, you must change your models and let Entity Framework change the database schema for you.

Suggested reading:

- *[Migration in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx)*
- *[Entity Framework Core Migrations](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations)*

Comment: This is very bold claim, which, I would argue is not true.

Comment: I explained as clearly as I could, it is not interpreting my change correctly. So editing the migration is the only way to get the results I need.

Comment: Yes, I added the *code-first* tag because I'm using code first.

Comment: **Code-first** means you edit your **code** model **first**. The opposite of **database-first**. Yeah, you can, but you shouldn't. This may be considered an anti-pattern, a code-smell.

Comment: @JonathanWood show us your intention and we'll help you. Show us how your tables and models are at this moment and what changes you want to make. You shouldn't try to hack the code. You'll be creating problems for you in the future. Imagine when you need to update the .net or ef version. You code may break.

Comment: I don't think he meant renaming tables and columns, but model classes/entities and their properties. Renaming is one of the actions, where EF Core has only very limited capabilities, because there are only very few scenarios, where it can distinguish between renaming an object (entity or property) and removing one and then adding another one. When renaming, you usually have to manually tweak the generated `Up()`/`Down()` code.

Comment: @richardsonwtr: Code first is the standard way to build the schema when building ASP.NET Core Razor Pages applications. I preferred database-first but you end up fighting the system all the way in .NET Core unless you do code-first. Please don't explain to me that code-first means that you edit your code first. This isn't kindergarten.